# Odata filter query to return all rows if condition is not met

Tags: odata, power-automate, powerapps

I am writing a filter query in my PowerApps that runs an Power Automate flow to filter data and export it and finally send to the user as email.

But I want the user to receive all the records if he/she leaves both of the text boxes blank. But with the approach I am writing, both text boxes must be filled, otherwise it returns zero records.

I am passing 2 parameters to the flow: First parameter is the query string and the second parameter is the email address of the user.

```
    ExportRows.Run(
    "substringof('" & SLT_Owner_Filter_txt.Text & "',SLT_Owner/Title) and substringof('" & SME_Filter_txt.Text & "',SME_1/Title)",
    User().Email
);
```

If I use "or" instead of and, it  returns all rows whether meets the condition or not. I hope I was able to elaborate what I need.
How can I do that?